# Hotkey for sbt shell in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Is there a hotkey in IntelliJ IDEA for opening the sbt shell? If not, how can I set up one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my IDEA `Ctrl+Shift+S` opens SBT shell. I'm not sure if it is standard shortcut or I've set it by myself. If not then in Settings in "Keymap" tab you can assign shortcut to any IDEA action.

Comment: Thanks! I've just found out, that under Mac OS the hotkey was `Shift+Commad+S`. However, even after switching to the sbt shell, the cursor in the shell does not become active, and I cannot even make it active using the `TAB` key. Any ideas on how to avoid having to use the mouse for this task?